# passing block to x.times method

Tags: ruby

I'm playing with ruby's built-in functions. I'm wondering how can I dynamically assign values and print it in a block.

Let me show you my example.

```
irb(main):001:0> i = 0
=> 0
irb(main):002:0> a = "a"
=> "a"
irb(main):003:0> while i<10
irb(main):004:1> x,a = a, a.next
irb(main):005:1> print x, " "
irb(main):006:1> i+=1
irb(main):007:1> end
a b c d e f g h i j => nil
```

Now I want to get same result with `x.times` method. `10.times {puts x,a=a, a.next}` raises error. How can I achieve same result using `x.times`?
My ruby version is 1.8.7

**Edit**: I tried a bit more and get this. But can't we use assignment like I've done in while loop? Except printing "a" and spaces, everything seems ok. Can you help me to print out "a" and spaces?

```
irb(main):011:0> x="a"
=> "a"
irb(main):012:0> 10.times {print x=x.next}
bcdefghijk=> 10
```

Comment: Did you know that v1.8.7 will celebrate its seventh birthday next month? Consider an upgrade.

Comment: i'm a bit conservative about upgrading. but maybe it's time to upgrade.  

p.s. my machine is living history -  java 1.2, python 2.5 :)

Comment: You think your computer is old? [Here's](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-h_PhC-2dt58/T2FYXiAihOI/AAAAAAAAAOI/NQ1PWrptvh8/s1600/1944+Mark+Computer.jpg) mine. (I'm just too cheap to upgrade.)

Comment: i just checked your profile, you are a living history. so, you witnessed cold war,software theft of soviet agents, and at least collapse of my homeland :)

Comment: for me, computer programmers older than 60 are "shining artefacts of past". they have been dealing with computers before and more before i was born,  they are enchanting. in this case, "de te fabula narratur", sir :)

Comment: I also witnessed VE Day (so to speak), and before that, going backward, fought in the Spanish Civil War, danced the Charleston survived the sinking of the Titanic, and, as a child, attended the Paris World Fair, where I climbed the newly-constructed Eiffel Tower.

Comment: That's interesting, "artefact" is a term my great, great, great grandchildren use when referring to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see an obvious way to do what you're asking for in a single line of code, but `a='a'; 10.t­imes {x,a = a, a.nex­t; print x,' '}` seems to work for me:

```
> a='a'; 10.ti­mes {x,a = a, a.nex­t; print­ x,' '}
=> "a b c d e f g h i j "
```

In Ruby you can use the `;` as a command separator, but write everything in one line.

Of course, you could just as easily write:

```
> a='a'; 
  10.ti­mes do
    x,a = a, a.nex­t; 
    print­ x,' '
  end
=> "a b c d e f g h i j "
```

and achieve the same result.

Comment: FWIW: you could use the standard-lib [`String::upto`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#method-i-upto) method: `"a".upto("j") {|s| print s, ' ' }`

Comment: Also, [@Matt Brictson](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4625365/matt-brictson)'s answer seems useful. Just don't, no matter what, expect to understand any answers you see for this on Code Golf.

Comment: @orde i actually revisit the page to post that upto also works, now i see you have already written it.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like an artificial and convoluted problem, but I assume it is more of a thought exercise to get familiar with functional Ruby.

Here are some more solutions to try on for size.

Too easy?

```
("a".."j").each { |c| print c, " " }
```

Alternatively, since you have a starting value ("a") and are "summing" subsequent values onto that "total", that feels like an application of `reduce`:

```
10.times.reduce("a") { |c| print c, " "; c.next }
```

The result of a `reduce` block is used as the input for the next iteration. I think this is the "assignment in a loop" behavior that you were aiming for.

Comment: yes, i'm just pushing my limits. a few minutes ago i've tried `a="a"; 1.upto(10) {x,a=a, a.next; print x, " "}` and get positive result :)

self-criticism: maybe using these methods are attractive  for beginners like me. but i'm afraid, this funny things also detains someone to write "old style" codes - like we have done with c in the past. and now, i have to make a desicion - to continue writing with limited syntax or benefit from these awesome stuff?

Answer (score 0):

I achieved my goal with some alternatives. Here I am listing them. I'll update by time.

```
10.times { x,a= a, a.succ; print x, " "}

1.upto(10) {x,a=a, a.next; print x, " "}
```